# Remove layout handle from xml

Tags: magento, layout, handles

I have a layout defined in some xml file found in a community module. Somehow I want to add a condition (ifconfig) by which the content of the block to be rendered or completely remove that handle and create one by myself so that I can have access to the block.

To be more specific, this is the handle I have in udprod.xml

```
    <_udprod_catalog_product_edit>
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="core/template" template="udprod/product_edit.phtml" />
        </reference>
    </_udprod_catalog_product_edit>
    <adminhtml_catalog_product_edit>
        <update handle="_udprod_catalog_product_edit" />
    </adminhtml_catalog_product_edit>
```

As you can see, the block has no name I can rely on. Is there any way I can remove the <_udprod_catalog_product_edit> handle from an xml file?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure that is possible, but I have a work around which I use to fix buggy 3rd party extensions:

**Create a new module**

A very simple one, only 2 files are required.

`app/etc/modules/Namespace_Fixer.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Namespace_Fixer>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
            <depends>
                <Broken_Module/>
            </depends>
        </Namespace_Fixer>
    </modules>
</config>
```

Note the depends, this is very important so that it is loaded after.

`app/code/local/Namespace/Fixer/etc/config.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Namespace_Fixer>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Namespace_Fixer>
    </modules>
    <global>
    </global>
    <frontend>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <broken_module> <!-- update this -->
                    <file>namespace/module_fixed.xml</file>
                </broken_module>
            </updates>
        </layout>
    </frontend>
</config>
```

Override the layout file to point to our new one.

**Duplicate the layout XML**

You want to point at the new XML, in there you can do the right thing and add a `name` to the block and call it where ever you want.

Comment: Sorry for not answering any sooner but I was still unable to figure out a method without the need of overriding the file. I ended up copying the file under my module and changed the code so that I added a name to that block. Not the most elegant solution but the best that came up. Thank you.

Comment: @blackseptember glad I helped, accept the answer if you have solve the issue using this method please.